# Flutter App runs with no problem, however it gives error in console (after adding firebase_messaging backgroundmesssagehandler)

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am having a working app, after adding firebase_messaging backgroundmessagehandler (added as per the package docs), it is giving following error, however the app & background messaging are working without any issues.

```
E/flutter ( 5828): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter ( 5828): NoSuchMethodError: No top-level getter '' declared.
E/flutter ( 5828): Receiver: top-level
E/flutter ( 5828): Tried calling:
E/flutter ( 5828): #0      NoSuchMethodError._throwNew  (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:202:5)
E/flutter ( 5828): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_isolate.cc(461)] Could not resolve main entrypoint function.
E/flutter ( 5828): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(205)] Could not run the isolate.
E/flutter ( 5828): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/engine.cc(137)] Engine not prepare and launch isolate.
E/flutter ( 5828): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
Error -32000 received from application: Could not run configuration in engine.
Error -32601 received from application: Method not found
method not available: ext.flutter.platformOverride
Error -32601 received from application: Method not found
method not available: ext.flutter.inspector.setPubRootDirectories
Error -32601 received from application: Method not foundmethod not available: ext.flutter.platformOverride
```

if I started the app afresh, no error will be generated till i hotReload / hotRestart the app for 3-4 times.

Any hint will be helpful, further i also wanted to know, does this type of errors leads to ANR/crash reports in playstore.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you have either a missing import or a parse error in your code. Try checking with [flutter analyze](https://docs.flutter.dev/testing/debugging#the-dart-analyzer).

No top-level getter '' declared means that it cannot find the value '' in the global scope. Either because it's not imported, or because there is a parse error before this error.